# What will happen to the interrupt latency ( or Jitter in the interrupt latency) when i lower the clock rate of a cpu

Tags: arm, real-time, interrupt, cpu-speed

I am having a baremetal program running on a ARM cpu which is processing interrupts of a real time application. Power is also a constraint, so i am thinking of playing with the frequency of that particular CPU. Is there a way with which i can predict the change ( in interrupt latency or the jitter in the interrupt latency) i can expect when i change the frequency. I know i can do this manually by implementing it and measuring it, but i would like to know whether there is a logical or mathematical way to do this.

Thanks.

Regards,
N

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just search for interrupt latency related to your architecture in official ARM docs. I.e. [Interrupt latency calculation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0164a/CIHDFIDE.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to find this information for Arm Cortex A9 architecture, But in the appendix there is some information about clock cycles consumed by instructions, I will have a look. Thanks for the pointer